# Notepad++ replace comma if is between two double quotes

Tags: notepad++

With notepad++ I would like to remove all comma only if they're between a couple of double quotes:

This is my source string:

```
0.00,0.00%,"1,926.10","2,873.68","2,365.13",14.29%
```

And i would like to obtain:

```
0.00,0.00%,"1926.10","2873.68","2365.13",14.29%
```

How to achieve this with notepad++?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:"|\G)\d+\K,`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:"|\G)        # non capture group, double quote OR restart from last match position
\d+             # 1 or more digits
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
,               # a comma
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### I would like to remove all commas only if they're between a couple of double quotes

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(\".*?),(.*?\")`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1\2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Enable ". matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

```
0.00,0.00%,"1,926.10","2,873.68","2,365.13",14.29%
```

**After**:

```
0.00,0.00%,"1926.10","2873.68","2365.13",14.29%
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: This will not work well if there are more than one comma like `"1,234,567.89","1,234,567.89"`

Comment: @Toto {shrug} It's what the OP asked for ...

Comment: Sure, but I think it's better to give a more general answer as OP may have not thought of more test cases.

Comment: @Toto Well you did, so I upvoted yours :)

Comment: Thanks, me too ;)

Comment: @Toto I didn't know you could upvote your own answers... j/k I know what you meant. :D